# android html download and parse error

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am trying to download the html file using the ul of the page. I am using Jsoup.
This is my code:

```
TextView ptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagetext);
    Document doc = null;
    try {
         doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect(mNewLinkUrl).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    Element meta = (Element) nl.item(0); 
    String title = meta.attr("title"); 
    ptext.append("\n" + mNewLinkUrl);
```

When running it, I am getting an error saying attr is not defined for the type element.
What have I done wrong? Pardon me if this seems trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that `Element` refers to [`org.jsoup.nodes.Element`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html), not something else. Verify your imports. Also ensure that `Document` refers to [`org.jsoup.nodes.Document`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html). It does namely not have a `getElementsByTagName()` method. Jsoup doesn't utilize any of the `org.w3c.dom` API.

Here's a complete example with the correct imports:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q4720189;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
        Element firstMeta = document.select("meta").first();
        String title = firstMeta.attr("title"); 
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Since the currently accepted answer was wrong I was just so kind to add the correct answer to avoid that others who encounter this question on their query would be put on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Element here is `org.w3c.dom.Element`. Then use `meta.getAttribute()` instead of `attr`. Element class simply doesn't have such method.

Comment: sorry, I was using android.sax.Element. Thank you for the reply.